# azure gateway probe always unhealty

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

How to debug the azure gateway probe? I have a setup which azure identifies as "unhealthy". The setup consist of one gateway with a http-setting with a custom probe. Behind it are two virtual machines.

When testing the path to the probes by direct ip, they both work. But the gateway identifies them as unhealthy.

Can I see a log somewhere why they are unhealty? 
My response code is a simple "OK" string with 200 OK status code.

Comment: You could check this [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics.md).

Comment: Thanks, thats perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check this [link](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics.md).

View back-end health through PowerShell:

```
Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHealth -Name ApplicationGateway1 -ResourceGroupName Contoso
```

Comment: You also check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502#problems-with-default-health-probe) to check your `health probe` configuration.